# How to insert the form data with array to the database using laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

I have a two table, One is called the header and another is called item details. 
Fields like date, supplier name, bill number will go to the header table and item name,qty and unit price goes to the item details table.

Now the problem is in item table we have form with 5 input field, user will enter the item details in the form and submit but only one item is saving. I know that we need to handle using array but I do not know how to write code for that.. Any one please let me?

```html
 <tr>       
        <td class="text-center">1</td>        
        <td ><input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" name = "item_name[]" id="row1"></td>
        <td ><input class="form-control text-center" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="qty"  id="qty1" onkeyup="calc1()" value=""></td>
        <td ><input class="form-control text-right" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="unit_price" id="price1" onkeyup="calc1()" value=""></td>
        <td > <input class="form-control text-right" type="text" name="amount" id="amount1" value="" disabled></td>
      </tr> 
       <tr>
        <td class="text-center">2</td>        
        <td ><input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" name = "item_name[]" id="row2"></td>
        <td ><input class="form-control text-center" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="qty" id="qty2" onkeyup="calc2()" value=""></td>
        <td ><input class="form-control text-right" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="unit_price" id="price2" onkeyup="calc2()" value=""></td>        
        <td > <input class="form-control text-right" type="text" name="amount" id="amount2" value="" disabled></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
       <td class="text-center">3</td>        
        <td ><input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase" name = "item_name[]" id="row3"></td>
        <td ><input class="form-control text-center" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="qty" id="qty3" onkeyup="calc3()" value=""></td>
        <td ><input class="form-control text-right" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" name="unit_price" id="price3" onkeyup="calc3()" value=""></td>
        <td > <input class="form-control text-right" type="text" name="amount" id="amount3" value="" disabled></td>
      </tr>
        

        <tr>
        <td class="text-center"></td>
        <td class="text-right" colspan="3"><label>Total</label></td>
        <td><input  type="text" class="form-control text-right" onkeyup="bill_total()" name = "total" id="total" disabled></td>        
      </tr>
```

```
enter code here
```

public function store(Request $request, Account $account, Item $item)
    {

```
    if($request->attach->getClientOriginalName())
    {
    $ext = $request->attach->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file = date('YmdHis').rand(1,99999).'.'.$ext;
    $request->attach->storeAs('public/categories',$file);
    }    
    else
    {
        $file='';
    }
    $account->attach = $file;
    $account->supp_name = $request->supp_name;
    $account->emp_name = $request->emp_name;
    $account->item_type = $request->item_type;
    $account->bill_date = $request->bill_date;
    $account->bill_amt = $request->bill_amt;
    $account->bill_no = $request->bill_no;
    $account->pay_mode = $request->pay_mode;
    $account->purpose = $request->purpose;
    $account->item_type = $request->item_type;
    $account->save();     

    $item->item_name = $request->item_name;        
    $item->qty = $request->qty;    
    $item->unit_price = $request->unit_price;    
    $item->save();

    return redirect('admin/accounts');
}
```

Comment: Post your code. What you've tried. This is not a code writing service. I suggest you read the documentation and watch tutorials.

Comment: Show us your `view` (html form) and `controller` code please.

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should change the type of your table column to array. 
Add something like this to your model (change the `options` word to your column name):

```
protected $casts = [
    'options' => 'array',
];
```

[Here is the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)

And in your view the input fields' names must be array too. Something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="item[]">
```

(Put as many input as you want)